# Given $\{A_n\}_{n ∈ ℕ}$, $\{B_n\}_{n ∈ ℕ}$ such that $ℙ[A_n \mathbin{\triangle} B_n]=0$ prove $ℙ[\bigcup_n A_n] = ℙ[\bigcup_n B_n]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \sigma, \mathbb P)$ be a probabilistic space. Given $A, B \in \sigma$, we define
> $$
>   \newcommand{\sdiff}{\mathbin{\triangle}}
>   A \sdiff B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c) \,.
> $$
> Given the sequences $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $\{B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of sets in $\sigma$ such that $\mathbb{P}[A_n \sdiff B_n] = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$,  prove that $\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n] = \mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty B_n]$.

I don’t really know how to approach this problem. What I’ve tried so far is the following:

As
$$
  \mathbb{P}[A_n \sdiff B_n]
  = \mathbb{P}[(A_n \cap B_n^c) \cup (A_n^c \cap B_n)]
  = \mathbb{P}[A_n \cap B_n^c] + \mathbb{P}[A_n^c \cap B_n]
  = 0
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\mathbb{P}[A_n \cap B_n^c] = \mathbb{P}[A_n^c \cap B_n] = 0$.

From this, we can conclude that
$$
  \mathbb{P}[A_n] - \mathbb{P}[A_n \cap B_n]
  = 0
  = \mathbb{P}[B_n] - \mathbb{P}[A_n \cap B_n] \,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
  \mathbb{P}[A_n] = \mathbb{P}[B_n] = \mathbb{P}[A_n \cap B_n] \,.
$$
However, I can’t find the way to relate this to the probability of the infinite union. I don’t know if I approached the problem wrong or if I’m just stuck.

I’d like someone to help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Call $A$ the union of all $A_n$ and $B$ the union of all $B_n$. You can show that $A \Delta B$ is contained in the union of all $A_n \Delta B_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}\Big(\bigcup_nA_n\Big)\triangle\Big(\bigcup_mB_m\Big)&=\left(\Big(\bigcup_nA_n\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcap_mB^c_m\Big)\right)\cup \left(\Big(\bigcup_nB_n\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcap_mA^c_m\Big)\right)\\
&=\Big(\bigcup_n\Big(A_n\cap\Big(\bigcap_mB^c_m\Big)\Big)\cup \Big(\bigcup_n\Big(B_n\cap\Big(\bigcap_mA^c_m\Big)\Big)\\
&\subset\Big(\bigcup_nA_n\cap B^c_n\Big)\cup\Big(\bigcup_nB_n\cap A^c_n\Big)=\bigcup_n\big(A_n\cap B^c_n)\cup(B_n\cap A^c_n)\\
&=\bigcup_n(A_n\triangle B_n)
\end{align}
Hence

$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\Big(\bigcup_nA_n\Big)\triangle\Big(\bigcup_mB_n\Big)\Big)\leq\sum_n\mu(A_n\triangle B_n)=0$$

Recall that $\mathbb{1}_{A\triangle B}=|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B|$. Thus, if $\mathbb{P}(A\triangle B)=\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B|]=0$, we have that $\mathbb{1}_A=\mathbb{1}_B$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. and so $\mathbb{P}[A]=\mathbb{P}[B]$. Applying this to
$A=\bigcup_nA_n$ and $B=\bigcup_nB_n$ yields the desired conclusion.